# how to prove the limit of a sequence using limit definition?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please, help me to prove that $x_n=\frac {n^2+n}{2n^2-3n-4}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}$.

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists n_0 \in \mathbb N$ such that $n>n_0\Rightarrow$
$\left|\frac{n^2+n}{2n^2-3n-4}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\epsilon \Rightarrow \left|\frac{5n+4}{4n^2-6n-8}\right|<\epsilon$. How to proceed from now on?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to prove by definition that if $a_n\to a, b_n\to b\neq 0$ then $a_n/b_n\to a/b$, and apply this to your limit? Divide through $n^2$.

Comment: Yes, but the challenge is to find a $n_0$ for which the inequality holds.

Answer (score 0):

It is best at this point to start making approximations, and then solve for $n_0$:

$$\left|\frac{5n+4}{4n^2-6n-8}\right|<\frac{9n}{4n^2}=\frac{9}{4n}$$

Now, notice if we choose $n_0>\frac{9}{4\epsilon}$, the above expression will be less than $\epsilon$ whenever $n>n_0$, just as desired.